# Access metrics API on Openshift Online 3?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, openshift-online

I'm running two Pods in my Openshift Online 3 project.

I want one Pod to know the resource utilization of the other.
The [k8s core metrics pipeline](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/core-metrics-pipeline/) from k8s 1.7+ is what I have in mind, but that isn't available on Openshift Online 3.

Where (URL) is the metrics (Hawkular) API for Openshift Online? How do I talk to it from a Pod inside the cluster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the metrics pipeline is still alpha it’s not enabled yet on OpenShift Online.  The Hawkular metrics are available - we anticipate having the metrics API available sometime in the next several months once it reaches beta.

Comment: How do I access the Hawkular API on OpenShift Online? The [Openshift Online docs*](https://docs.openshift.com/online/welcome/index.html) don't mention Hawkular (no search results).

I have seen [these*](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.6/install_config/cluster_metrics.html#cluster-metrics-accessing-hawkular-metrics-directly) [docs*](https://github.com/openshift/origin-metrics/blob/master/docs/hawkular_metrics.adoc), but I'm immediately stuck:

`-X GET https://hawkular-metrics.example.com/hawkular/metrics/metrics`

What URL do I use?

Comment: It depends on the cluster that you're using. For example, if you are on starter-us-east-1, the URL would be https://metrics.starter-us-east-1.openshift.com/hawkular/metrics

Comment: The URL works! But when I query `.../hawkular/metrics/metrics` (with bearer token and hawkular-tenant header), I receive an error: `{"errorMsg":"Failed to perform operation due to an error: Cassandra timeout during read query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded)"}`.